# What does it mean to apply a vector field to a scalar function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-fields

In a textbook I am reading, the author writes:

> Be careful not to confuse the notations $fX$ and $Xf$, the first is a smooth vector field, the second is a real valued function.

If we go down into a specific coordinate representation of $X$ it is a function that eats points in a smooth manifold and spits out a vector, so ti would look like this:

$X(p) = (X^1(p), \cdots, X^n(p))$

Similarly we would get:

$fX(p) = f(p)X(p) = f(p)(X(p) = (X^1(p), \cdots, X^n(p)))$

I am having a hard time understanding what $Xf$ means. $f$ spits out scalars, so it;s output cannot be an input of $X$.

The book describes the action of a vector field on a scalar funciton as follows:

$$(Xf)(p) = Xpf$$

Which is not very clear to me, at face value and naively reading the notation, that looks like the scalar product of a vector, which is just $fX$ but we know that it is not what that is supposed to represent.

Comment: In the coordinate dependent setting the application of a vector field corresponds to the regular directional derivative by a vector. In local coordinates $Xf(x^1, ..., x^n):= \sum_{i\leq n} X^i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(x^1, ... x^n)$. This should correspond with the familiar notion from vector calculus.

Comment: $X^i$ being the ith component function of the vector field?

Comment: Yes. $X^i$ is a (typically smooth) function $M \to \mathbb{R}$, and in coordinates, $X=\sum_{i=1}^n X^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$.

Comment: That $Xpf$ should be $X_p f$. I find it hard to believe a book would give such a definition without previously defining vectors as differential operators - there might be an earlier chapter you skimmed over that could help you understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "action" of a vector $X_p$ on a scalar function $f$ is to take the derivative of $f$ in the direction $X_p$. If $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $X_p$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $X_p f=\frac{d}{dt}(f(p+tX_p))$. More generally, if $f \in C^1(M)$ for some manifold $M$, let $\gamma:(-1,1) \to M$ be any $C^1$ curve such that $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\dot{\gamma}(0)=X_p$. Then $X_p f=\frac{d}{dt}(f(\gamma(t)))|_{t=0}$.

Answer (score 1):

A smooth vector field $X \colon U \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $U$ open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be identified with the partial differential operator $\sum_{j = 1}^{n}X_j(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$. Then if $f \in C^{\infty}(U)$, $Xf \in C^{\infty}(U)$ is the function defined by $Xf(x) = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}X_j(x)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x)$.